# How can I make a Ruby symbol pointer point to something else instead?

Tags: ruby, pointers, tree, symbols

I'm pretty sure this is impossible, but it's awfully tempting.

I'm working with tree structures, made of hashes within arrays within hashes, et cetera. The hierarchy bottoms out in symbols (i. e., the leaves of the tree are all symbols). I'm writing a method that takes one of these trees and replaces all instances of a specific symbol with another tree (i. e. it extends the tree by replacing some leaves with another tree). The symbol could appear in many places all over the tree, and traversing the tree could be a heavy operation. Ruby stores symbols once, and then just puts pointers to it on the leaves. Is there any way I can take advantage of this fact by replacing the symbol at the pointer location with the other tree?

I should probably just learn C. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution that I have, and it is **VERY** hacky! I would think twice before you use this.

**Explanation**

Ruby is pass by reference, but many Ruby methods return objects. Meaning an assignment will overwrite the reference to a previous object instead of overwriting the object referenced.

We can get around this by creating a wrapper class which we never overwrite. This way we can change the contents and have multiple variables update.

```
class Pointer
  attr_accessor :obj
end

a = Pointer.new
a.obj = "foo"
b = a

puts a.obj
puts b.obj

puts "Updating"
a.obj = "bar"

puts a.obj
puts b.obj
```

**Output**

```
foo
foo
Updating
bar
bar
```

Comment: I think the answer to my question is basically 'no'. But if I really needed the functionality, this is how I would do it!

Answer (score 2):

I think your design for the architecture of that object is wrong. Rather than having a tree structure, you should just have a single hash representing all the branchings.

For example, suppose you have a tree like this:

```
- Homonoidea
  - Hylobatidae
    - Hylobates
  - Hominidae
    - Pongo
    - Gorilla
    - Pan
    - Homo
```

Rather than keeping a tree structure, you can have a single hash like this:

```
@hash = {
  root: [:homonoidea],
  homonoidea: [:hylobatidae, :hominidae],
  hylobatidae: [:hylobates],
  hominidae: [:pongo, :gorilla, :pan, :homo],
}
```

It is easy to expand this into a tree structure whenever you need. And when you want to replace one of the branchings, it is easy. Also, when you have identical subtrees within the tree as you mentioned in the question, keeping it like I suggest will avoid redundancy.